# PHP: How to compare two values of MongoDB on basis of id and return similar values?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database where I am trying to **find value on basis of $_id**, when I found $id value it will start **searching similar **$_id** value in all DB** and after matching all similar $_id it will prints similar values.

My DB is like

```
    MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fca7fd2082ba613cfee8766
                )

            [title] => KanKan  
            [summary] => Developer
)
)

MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fca7fdd082ba613cfee8768
                )

            [title] => Michelle 
            [summary] => Designer
)
)

MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fca7fd2082ba613cfee8766
                )

            [title] => Rakes
            [summary] => Copyrighter
)
)
```

Trying to Do something like this -

```
foreach($cursor as $row){
   
        $i=0;

      while ($i < count($row)) {

  print_r($row["title"]);
      }
 
    }
```

Looking for Better suggestion to complete my require too.